# How to recover Windows 8 without password?

Tags: windows-8, password-recovery, pin

I would normally log in with a PIN to use my laptop, but all of a sudden the "Sign-In Options" button used to enter a PIN had disappeared, and I was only able to enter a password, which I do not know. I'd like to try to reformat, but do not know if this is possible without being able to login. What are my options? I also do not have any discs. The laptop did not come with any.

Thanks

Comment: If you know the PIN just restart the computer.

Comment: after restarting, the "Sign-In Options" button is still missing, so I do not have the option to use the PIN.

Comment: Is it a Microsoft account (with an email)?

Comment: Is there a sticker on the bottom with product key and does it does it not say OEM?

Comment: Yes, it's a Microsoft account. I tried changing the password for that account, though still no luck (not even sure if that's the password that I'm supposed to be using). No, I don't see a sticker with OEM on it.

Comment: @cybernard - Windows 8 OEM products ( laptop, desktop, ect ) do not come with COA stickers.

Answer (score 0):

Get partedmagic or another bootable cd/dvd that contains chntpass

1. Boot from said disc.
2. Clear the password
3. save the changes.
4. quit
5. reboot login with a blank password (just hit )